# best way to align heading text with div on the same line in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best approach to allign some div on the same line as heading in bootstrap 3?

```
    <h2>Company Name SA</h2>
    <div>
        <span class="badge badge-danger">3 Alerts</span>
        <span class="badge badge-warning">2 Warnings</span>
    </div>
```

I need this to be on the same line.

This is my solution:

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left"><h2>Orange Communications SA</h2></div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <span class="badge badge-danger">3 Alerts</span>
            <span class="badge badge-warning">2 Warnings</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show css code?

Comment: I don't think he needs to show any CSS assuming he's using default Bootstrap classes and styles...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the spans inside the h2? That should work:

```
<h2>
    Company Name SA
    <span class="badge badge-danger">3 Alerts</span>
    <span class="badge badge-warning">2 Warnings</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue, but the spans and text inside the spans will probably be h2 size instead of normal font size, depending on the CSS

Comment: @vogomatix Normally I would agree, but Bootstrap takes care of such cases.

Comment: I'm not saying Bootstrap doesn't take care of it, just that visually the two arrangements will be different...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using clearfix class, use a *container* or *row* class for the outer div.

Bootstrap 3 also supports *text-left*, *text-right* and *text-center* classes